# Awk loop through a file line by line and use the value to get row from a csv file containing the value of that line

Tags: awk

I have 2 files, the first one:

values.txt

```
test@gmail.com
test1@gmail.com
test3@gmail.com
test4@gmail.com
test5@gmail.com
test6@gmail.com
test7@gmail.com
test8@gmail.com
test9@gmail.com
test10@gmail.com
```

data.csv

```
"username","email"
"user","test@gmail.com"
"user1","test1@gmail.com"
"user2","test3@gmail.com"
"user4","test4@gmail.com"
"user456","loka@gmail.com"
"user789","lopa@gmail.com"
"user5","test7@gmail.com"
"user","xpos@gmail.com"
"user5","test9@gmail.com"
"user","xpx@gmail.com"
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
"user","test@gmail.com"
"user1","test1@gmail.com"
"user2","test3@gmail.com"
"user4","test4@gmail.com"
"user5","test7@gmail.com"
"user5","test9@gmail.com"
```

What I was able to do :

```
awk -F',' '$2 ~ /test9@gmail.com/ {print $0}' data.csv > test1.csv
```

This will create a new file test1.csv containing:

```
"user5","test9@gmail.com"
```

Couldn't figure out how to loop through the file and exchange the `test9@gmail.com` with the line of the values.txt

Comment: Is there a specific reason for `awk`? `grep` can do this without hassle: `grep -f values.txt data.csv`

Comment: @Fiximan grep alone can't do this particular job robustly as it needs a regexp match to isolate the 2nd field but also a literal string match to only match the exact values of those fields and you can't do both a regexp and a string match in grep.

Comment: Cross-posted at StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/q/66016240) and AskUbuntu (askubuntu.com/q/1313072)

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F, '
  NR==FNR{ a["\""$1"\""]; next }
  $2 in a
' values.txt data.csv
```

First input file: Save each field in an array `a` and prefix/suffix each key with `"`. Continue with the `next` record.

Second input file: Test if the second field exists in array `a`. The default action prints the record if the condition is true.

Comment: Is there a way to save the result in a file ? Because unfortunately nothing is being displayed .

Comment: The result is written to stdout. If not, then there's something wrong. You can redirect the output to a file if you add a redirection to the last line: `... data.csv > outfile`

Comment: @Taleb if nothing is being displayed then chances are you have DOS line endings, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it, and so the array is being populated with `"test@gmail.com\r"` but compared against `"test@gmail.com"\r`